# What does LIBXML_NOENT do (and why isn't it called LIBXML_ENT)?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, libxml2

In PHP, one can pass optional arguments to various XML parsers, one of them being `LIBXML_NOENT`. The [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php) has this to say about it:

> LIBXML_NOENT (integer)
>      Substitute entities

`Substitute entities` isn't very informative (what entities? when are they substituted?). But I think it's fair to assume that `NOENT` is short for `NO_ENTITIES` or `NO_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES`, so to me it seems to be a fair assumption that this flag disables the parsing of (external) entities.

But that is indeed *not* the case:

```
$xml = '<!DOCTYPE root [<!ENTITY c PUBLIC "bar" "/etc/passwd">]>
<test>&c;</test>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml, LIBXML_NOENT);
echo $dom->textContent;
```

The result is that the content of /etc/passwd is echoed. Without the `LIBXML_NOENT` argument this is not the case.

For non-external entities, the flag doesn't seem to have any effect. Example:

```
$xml = '<!DOCTYPE root [<!ENTITY c "TEST">]>
<test>&c;</test>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
echo $dom->textContent;
```

The result of this code is "TEST", with and without `LIBXML_NOENT`.

The flag doesn't seem to have any effect on pre-defined entities such as `&lt;`.

So my questions are:

- What exactly does the `LIBXML_NOENT` flag do?
- Why is it called `LIBXML_NOENT`? What is it short for, and wouldn't `LIBXML_ENT` or `LIBXML_PARSE_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES` be a better fit?
- Is there a flag that actually prevents the parsing of all entities?

Comment: It's [mapped to](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/ef0279b640b19f6294a1429f9e04019b1f72d69c/ext/libxml/libxml.c#L801) the libxml constant `XML_PARSE_NOENT` if that gives you anything to search on. It is very vaguely described...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Q: What exactly does the LIBXML_NOENT flag do?**

The flag enables the substitution of XML character entity references, external or not.

**Q: Why is it called LIBXML_NOENT? What is it short for, and wouldn't LIBXML_ENT or LIBXML_PARSE_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES be a better fit?**

The name is indeed misleading. I think that `NOENT` simply means that the node tree of the parsed document won't contain any entity nodes, so the parser will substitute entities. Without `NOENT`, the parser creates [DOMEntityReference](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domentityreference.php) nodes for entity references.

**Q: Is there a flag that actually prevents the parsing of all entities?**

`LIBXML_NOENT` enables the substitution of *all* entity references. If you don't want entities to be expanded, simply omit the flag. For example

```
$xml = '<!DOCTYPE test [<!ENTITY c "TEST">]>
<test>&c;</test>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

prints

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE test [
<!ENTITY c "TEST">
]>
<test>&c;</test>
```

It seems that `textContent` replaces entities on its own which might be a peculiarity of the PHP bindings. Without `LIBXML_NOENT`, it leads to different behavior for internal and external entities because the latter won't be loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In your answer to the third question, you mean `enables` instead of `disables`, right? And is there a way to access the DOM without entities being parsed? Because it's not just `textContent` that does it, it's also `$dom->getElementsByTagName('test')->item(0)->nodeValue`. If I do `print_r($dom->childNodes->item(1));` it also seems to always be parsed, there is no `DOMEntityReference` for internal entities. But for external entities, `LIBXML_NOENT` makes a difference here. The `saveXML` output is indeed different though, even for internal entities.

Comment: @tim I fixed the answer to the third question. `nodeValue` and `textContent` are typically the same. To access the `DOMEntityReference` node, try `$dom->documentElement->childNodes->item(0)` or `$dom->documentElement->firstChild`.